# Android: Duplicate entry in build.gradle zip exception in buildconfig.class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to run my Android application with Android Studio, and it showed an error saying the following message.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sap/maf/uicontrols/logonui/res/BuildConfig.class
```

It seems like there's a duplicate library, so that's why it stops running. But I honestly don't know which I should fix with the build.gradle file. So I put my build.gradle file here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "abcd.test.com.abcd"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile project(':maflogonui12122')
compile project(':mafsettingscreen12122')
compile project(':mafuicomponents12122')
compile files('libs/AfariaSLL-7.00.6169.0.jar')
compile files('libs/ClientHubSLL-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/ClientLog-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/Common-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/Connectivity-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/CoreServices-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/DataVaultLib-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/E2ETrace-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/HttpConvAuthFlows-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/HttpConversation-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/maflogger-1.212.2.jar')
compile files('libs/maflogoncore-1.212.2.jar')
compile files('libs/maflogonui.jar')
compile files('libs/mafsettingscreen.jar')
compile files('libs/mafuicomponents.jar')
compile files('libs/MobilePlace.jar')
compile files('libs/ODataAPI-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/odataoffline.jar')
compile files('libs/ODataOnline-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/perflib-1.2.0.jar')
compile files('libs/Request-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/sap-e2etrace-2.3.5.300.jar')
compile files('libs/SupportabilityFacade-3.12.2.jar')
compile files('libs/XscriptParser-3.12.2.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: One or more of your maf prefix libraries can be cause of this. They might be having files with same names internally.

Comment: Both of them are required. Anyways i still tried removing both one by one(with cleanup), still the same error persists.

Comment: there ae 5 of them not 2 only

Comment: All of them are required, the application used to work fine before me including multidex in the gradle file. I included multidex here and the application stopped working.

Comment: @KushagraJain How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your compile twice maf-realted components twice: first as project and second time as lib (like you have compile project(':maflogonui12122') but also compile files('libs/maflogonui.jar')). So, try to remove one of them.

Comment: Both of them are required. Anyways i still tried removing both one by one(with cleanup), still the same error persists.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting same problem and I found solution for this.

Change your project's minSdkVersion to 21. :)

Comment: That's the worst suggestion. I want my app to be compatible to Android 16